# Autosized page in XSL-FO?

Tags: report, xsl-fo, bi-publisher, page-size

is it possible to program a `XSL-FO` template using an autosized `page-width` and `page-height` expression?

Comment: What do you mean by 'auto-sized'?

Comment: Hello Tony, i've got a template generating a table with different amount of columns depending on different XML-Data. So every table has got a different width. now i want the tables have got every time the same border size at the left and right side. Therefore i need something like an autosized page. Is it possible in XSL-FO?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the formatter that you're using, but if you know the number and width of the columns, can't you calculate the page width that you want?

Comment: With most FO Processors you can get the area tree representation of the document. You could set an overly large width and height on the page, format the document according to your rules and then put some simple code in place to process the area tree and adjust page width and height. That said, it is unclear to me your "width" question as making the page wider could change the column widths unless they are fixed. And if they are fixed, you should be able to know the page width.